# Store Large value in Oracle Database from C#

Tags: c#, oracle, long-integer

I want to store 20 numbers(eg.12345678901234567890) in oracle database. I've used NUMBER data type in oracle database and when I pass long data type from the C# end it's getting error,

> > Error is : Value was either too large or too small for an Int64.

### Code

```
 _newsObj.SUB_AGENCY_ID = long.Parse(this.txtSubAgency.Text);
```

How can i store my above example data in oracle database ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) cannot store `12345678901234567890` big number, you can use `decimal` instead.

```
decimal.Parse(this.txtSubAgency.Text)
```

Comment: Is this value can store NUMBER field in Oracle ?

Comment: yes sure, there is nothing to do with oracle. NUMBER can store up to 38 digits length